# How to sort the files and directories in the Project Explorer of Eclipse Juno?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I forgot how to set the sorting status of files in the Project Explorer of Eclipse Juno as follows:

```
    a      <--this is a directory
    b.txt  <--this is a file
    bb     <--this is a directory
    cc.txt <--this is a file
    zz.txt <--this is a file
```

But I remember that the default sorting is as follows:

```
   a
   bb
   b.txt
   cc.txt
   zz.txt
```

Could anyone give me some advice on how to reset the sorting into the default status? Thanks!

Comment: What type of project is this? A screen-shot might make it easier to see what types of files are affected.

Comment: Hi, @Duncan, this is a `C++` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An rude way is to delete the `~/.eclipse` directory.